# Azure DevOps Server - get `scope` of the project

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I have Azure DevOps Server v2019.Update1.1 and I want use `tfssecurity` cli to create new groups in the project (because graph api is not available for on-premise yet)

To do so I need `scope` parameter which will identify project. From documentation: "Specifies the URI of the project for which you want to display groups. To obtain the URI for a project, open Team Explorer, right-click the project, click Properties, and copy the entire entry for URL"

From google results it looks like "vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/6868ab48-73f8-499d-b4c5-bb743f68ad87"

Is there a way to get that value programatically via cli or api?

Comment: Did you look at the REST API documentation around projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope is the URI of the project, whose format is `vstfs://Classification/TeamProject/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` is the id of the project. You can get the project id from [Projects - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) REST api:

`GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0`

Or you can use the following code to retrieve the URI:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;

namespace GetTeamProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            VssCredentials cred = new VssClientCredentials();
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFS2019:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"), cred);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            ICommonStructureService css = tpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
            ProjectInfo[] projects = css.ListProjects();
            foreach (ProjectInfo pro in projects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pro.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(pro.Uri);
            }

        }
    }
}
```